# Drop down terminal as smooth as gnome-shell's 'looking glass'

Tags: software-recommendation, gnome, looking-glass

Is there a drop down terminal as smooth as gnome-shell's 'looking glass' that has a normal bash shell?

Gnome-shell's looking glass (alt+f2 then lg then enter) is so smooth. I'd like to see a simple gnome-terminal session in a drop down that smooth.

I know you can smooth drop down Tilda, but, well, it flashes and it's not that smooth. I dislike Guake's excessive ui chrome and yukake is outta place. Any other solutions? Has anyone taken the 'looking glass' code and baked a gnome-terminal into it?

Comment: You tried the 3 I know of, wondering if anyone has a 4th or 5th =)

Comment: I'm willing to bet that over the next year there will be a version of a drop down terminal based of the 'looking-lass.' At least I hope so

Comment: I agree that this would be cool, and with the lookglass extension you could probably add it to the looking glass window as one of the tabs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a new GNOME Shell extension that makes exactly what you need!

It's called [Drop Down Terminal](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/442/drop-down-terminal/). It's compatible with GNOME Shell 3.6 (and older versions as far as I know).
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go with Guake terminal. It's easy to customize, and works like a charm.

Look for it in the Software Centre.

Comment: Can I get rid of the huge tab bar that is part of the ui at the bottom of guake?

Comment: yes you can. Open up the Guake Preferences and uncheck "Show tab bar" under General->Main Window. It's the last checkbutton in the first preferences tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Tilda](http://tilda.sourceforge.net/tildadoc.php), even though all the features aren't enabled out of the box, the preference editor lets you adjust everything easily, you can adjust the animation speed rates, width, size, fading, etc.

EDIT: Also, it only blinks if you don't have compositing enabled system-wide. It runs as a background process underneath EVERYTHING even TTY's

Comment: How can I tell if I don't have compositing enabled system-wide? I believe I do and it is nowhere near as close to the looking glass

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
https://github.com/zzrough/gs-extensions-drop-down-terminal

It is smooth and nice. It hasn't got tabs, but you can achieve simillar effect by using byobu:
https://launchpad.net/byobu

Answer (score 1):

yet another drop-down terminal with some unique features https://github.com/linvinus/AltYo

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool which can be used to add "drop-down" feature to ANY application: https://github.com/shivams/ddan

I use it to drop-down my `gnome-terminal` (and hence obviating `guake`). It feels smooth on Unity.